# Can this different battery model work with my laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, dell-inspiron

The laptop battery which I have currently and is not working for my Dell 5520 15R laptop is having the specs as:
1) Type: 8858X, 48Wh Standard Li-on battery, 11.1 V, 4080 mAh

I ordered the battery but they sent me the battery with the following specs:
2) Type : T54FJ , 60Wh Standard Li-on battery, 11.1 V, 5100mAh

As you can see the Ratings of Wh and mAh are different, can someone please suggest if this is fine for my laptop and also what difference does these 2 ratings will affect my laptop with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it fits it should be fine. All you did was buy a battery with a larger capacity.

Comment: Wouldnt it damage my laptop since the Wh rating is significantly different?

Comment: @akshhat If you are thirsty and need for example 1 liter of water. If I gave you a 2-liter bottle, you will drink the 1 liter you need and the rest will be useful when you get thirsty again. You bought a higher capacity battery than the older one, so the laptop will consume what it needs for a longer time than before. What damages your laptop is a higher voltage, and both batteries are 11.1V so you are safe.

Comment: @akshat - No.  The amount of wattage per hour the battery will consume isn't a concern in a case like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine, you have nothing to worry about.
60Wh and 5100mAh are capacity indicators, meaning that the new battery will last longer (have larger capacity) than the default one.

Judging by the voltage and capacity, both batteries are 6-cell batteries.
The 4080mAh containes 6 2000mAh Li-Ion 18650-typse cells, while the 5100mAh one contains 6 2600mAh cells.

So, the difference: the battery should last longer with approximatively 20% compared to the original one.

Comment: Wouldnt it damage my laptop since the Wh rating is significantly different?

Comment: Negative. The notebook will draw the same current, regardless of the capacity of the battery. Lets say that the laptop would consume 24W, that would mean that at 48Wh the battery would last 2 hours. At 60Wh, it will last 2.5 hours.

Comment: @akshat - It may take a little longer to fully charge the battery, depending on the AC adapter capacity and the charging circuit in the laptop.

Comment: Yes, charge time will also be longer, proportionally.

Answer (score -2):

Usually batteries with same size and higher capacity have larger internal impedance. It means the battery with smaller capacity can give larger current. Maybe your notebook requires it. To give the better answer there is not enough data. By the way you can find tables of compatibility on official Dell web site. (These batteries are designed for different series of notebooks)

Comment: This information is basically incorrect, and doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: could you explain why ?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Super User.  It isn't clear why a higher capacity would have higher impedence, but the current capability is not inversely related to capacity.  Even if it was, that wouldn't mean that it can't provide the required power.  Additional information isn't required to answer the question (see Overmind's answer).  It could be that the higher capacity battery ships standard with some other models, but there's no evidence that it is not compatible with this model.  So pretty much everything in this post is either incorrect, unsupported, or irrelevant to what was asked.

Comment: You can take a look at http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp512564f. Feel free to ask ;)

Comment: That would all be buried in the design considerations; the batteries still need to deliver the required current.  You could make a more effective case if you could cite evidence that this particular battery, or even any high-capacity battery legitimately sold as a compatible replacement for any laptop, was unable to deliver the required current.  In general, lithium batteries don't have a problem delivering high current (one of the reasons for their tendency to explode when shorted).